# jQuery post id send and while-loop white page

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, while-loop, modal-dialog

I'm a junior developer and I have a problem when send, with post method, an id with jQuery to a external page with inside a while loop modal.

This is my jQuery call that send the button clicked id to external PHP page that trough a while loop write data retrieved from MySQL database.

When I clicking the button the confirm modify modal is showed, and then if modify button of the modal is clicked, load the external page in the div #container_ajax, and for last toggle (close) the confirm modify modal.

```js
$(document).on("click", '.tasto-modifica-veicolo', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $("#modal-preconferma-modifica").modal("toggle");
  if ($("#btn_allow_mod_veicolo").on("click", function() {
      $('#container_ajax').load("modifica_veicolo.php", "#container_ajax");
      $.post({
        type: "post",
        url: "modifica_veicolo.php",
        data: {
          "id_modifica_veicolo": id
        },
        success: function() {
          $("#modal-preconferma-modifica").modal("toggle");
        },
      });
    }));
});
```

And to here all work done, but the external page is loaded with blank page.

Opening the developer console in the Preview tab the page is showed and work perfectly with while loop, but in front-end white page.

If instead of a variable post, in MySQL query I write manually a id , the code work perfectly when I call with jQuery.

Is it like external URL page not received the post data and while loop receive a variable blank without a id to execute... but in developer preview tab show correctly !

**The id is sent correctly**
[image: The id is sent correctly]

**In preview tab the page show correctly**
[image: In preview tab the page show correctly]

(include('config.php'); there is a MySQL connection string.

The form "form-modifica-veicolo" is needed for sending data to update query.

```
<?php

include('config.php');
$id_modifica_veicolo = $_POST['id_modifica_veicolo'];
$query_veicolodamodificare="SELECT * FROM ws_veicoli WHERE ID = '$id_modifica_veicolo'";
$result_veicolodamodificare= $conn->query($query_veicolodamodificare);
while ($row_veicolo = $result_veicolodamodificare->fetch_assoc()){
?>


<div class='modal fade show d-block' id='modal_modifica_veicolo' tabindex='-1'>
<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
<div class='modal-content'>
<div class='modal-header border-0'>
<h5 class='modal-title fw-bold'>Modifica veicolo</h5>
<button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'></button>
</div>
<div class='modal-body'>
<div class='col-12 d-flex flex-wrap flex-row'>
<form method='POST' id='form-modifica-veicolo'>

    <div class='col-lg-4 col-12 p-1'>
    <label>Targa</label>
    <input name='targa' id='targa' value='$row_veicolo[Targa]' class='form-control mt-2 mb-2 rounded-5' type='text' maxlength='7' onkeyup='this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();'>
    </div>

</form>
<div class='modal-footer border-0'>
<button type='button' class='btn' data-bs-dismiss='modal'>Annulla</button>
<button type='button' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#modal_modifica_veicolo' data-bs-dismiss='modal' class='btn btn-primary rounded-5'>Salva</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is a short part of all code...

Inserting id manually in MySQL query of the external page, the code work perfectly with jQuery call.

If I send id with jQuery, white page...

Comment: `if ($("#btn_allow_mod_veicolo").on("click",` is likely not dong what you think it might do. - remove the if() completely

Comment: Done, but nothing changed... always blank page

Answer (score 0):

You want to POST only:

```js
$(document).on("click", '.tasto-modifica-veicolo', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $("#modal-preconferma-modifica").modal("toggle");
  $("#btn_allow_mod_veicolo").on("click", function() {
    $.post({
      url: "modifica_veicolo.php",
      data: {
        "id_modifica_veicolo": id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#container_ajax').html(data); // but return only the content of the div
        $("#modal-preconferma-modifica").modal("toggle");
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Test

```js
$(document).on("click", '.tasto-modifica-veicolo', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-id='1' type='button' class='tasto-modifica-veicolo btn'><i class='fa-solid text-secondary fa-file-pen'></i>1</button>
<button data-id='2' type='button' class='tasto-modifica-veicolo btn'><i class='fa-solid text-secondary fa-file-pen'></i>2</button>
<button data-id='3' type='button' class='tasto-modifica-veicolo btn'><i class='fa-solid text-secondary fa-file-pen'></i>3</button>
```

Comment: Nothing to do, if i insert the id manually in the MYSQL query all work done, but if sent not work.

Comment: Then you need to see if it is correct. Do a `console.log($(this).data('id'))`

Comment: In console it show "undefined".

Comment: So you need to see if the element `tasto-modifica-veicolo` has a data-id. I do not see that element anywhere

Comment: This is button in a while loop table that call function: <button data-id='$row[ID]' type='button' class='tasto-modifica-veicolo btn'><i class='fa-solid text-secondary fa-file-pen'></i></button>

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (see the test)

Comment: When i click on button, the id sent is right for the row selected. So, i have a table  generate with a while loop of a vehicles list, for every row there is a button to modify, and every data-id attribute of each button has different id as for MYSQL database. The problem is that jquery sent the id but url not receive nothing, because also if i change the variable id with a number manually, jquery sent this number but page stay white. All work right only if i write the number already in the query into php page.

Comment: var_dump the $_POST to see where it went

Comment: It show:   string(2) "14"    where 14 is the id sent.

Comment: `$_POST["id_modifica_veicolo"] = "14"`

Comment: Yes, if id is declared works, but id must be dynamic when i click button sending the id of mysql database row. I cant understand because in preview of developer tools is show and when modal is visible inputs are blank.